# Laurent series for $(\sin 2z)/z^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to find the Laurent series for $(\sin2z)/z^3$ in $|z|>0$, but I really don't know how to start. And I thought that in this area it's a Taylor serie because the singularity isn't in the area, am I right? But what is then your $z_0$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution by Eli E is good, but I wanted to answer your question about the Taylor's series.  You have a singularity at z = 0, so there is no Taylor's expansion at that point. You can have a Taylor's expansion at any other point in the plane, and its radius of convergence will be the distance from that point to the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laurent series  of $sin(z) = {z}-\frac{z^3}{3! }\dots$ so the series for $sin(2z)=2z-\frac{(2z)^3}{3! } \dots$

divide this in $z^3$ and you will get that the Laurent series of $ \frac{sin(2z)}{z^3} $$$\frac{sin(2z)}{z^3} =\frac{2}{z^2}-\frac{2^3}{3! }+\frac{2^5z^2}{5! }-\frac{2^7z^4}{7! } \dots
$$

Comment: I was just about to say that, you're fast!

Comment: I am trying my best :D

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with finding the series for $\sin 2z$ and then dividing that series by $z^3$?  You will have a term proportional to $1/z^2$, but that is unavoidable unless you start your series from some other particular point, $z=1$ or $z=1/2$ or whatever.

Comment: Oo now I see my mistake I used sinz taylor serie this afternoon and not sin2z  and then got a wrong answer. But how do I know that I have to make a Maclaurin serie?

Comment: Don't worry about the mistake.  I do stuff like that all the time.  I'm not sure I understand your question, though.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: MacLaurin is the Taylor series at x=0. If your expression can be represented as fraction of holomorphic functions, you replace both by their Taylor or MacLaurin series and use power series division to get the Laurent series.